# Does anyone have insight into whether MonoDroid is really dead?

Tags: c#, .net, monodroid

My company just recently invested in the [Mono for Android](http://mono-android.net/) tools for Visual Studio as we have a lot of .NET developers and were impressed with how powerful the monodroid tools seemed. After reading the [ZDNet Post](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/is-mono-dead-is-novell-dying/8821#) I was saddened to see that this project may be dead. Is there anyone out there who might know anything more about this than what is listed in that article? Apparently legions of developers were let go from the mono project but I'm wondering if it's true. Any information would be greatly appreciated. We just bought the Enterprise 5 license, which was pretty costly and I'd be pretty mad if it died after I just bought this thing and started learning it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be a conflict in the layoff announcement - `all technology roadmaps remain intact` vs. `We have re-established Nuremburg as the headquarters of our SUSE business unit and the prioritization and resourcing of certain development efforts - including Mono - will now be determined by the business unit leaders there.` ([citation of Attachmate Group CEO](http://blog.internetnews.com/skerner/2011/05/attachmate-lays-off-mono-emplo.html))

[Miguel de Icaza stated in his twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/migueldeicaza) account that: `I'll have a blog post next Monday, I am tied up until then`.

<strike>I would suggest waiting for the next Monday and check what comes out at [http://tirania.org/blog/]</strike>[3](http://tirania.org/blog/).

**UPDATE**:
On Monday Miguel de Icaza announced that he and former members of the Mono team founded a new startup called Xamarin that will:

- Build a new commercial .NET offering for iOS
- Build a new commercial .NET offering for Android
- Continue to contribute, maintain and develop the open source Mono and Moonlight components.
- Explore the Moonlight opportunities in the mobile space and the Mac appstore.

They seems to plan to deliver a MonoTouch replacement. First version is expected to be available in 3-4 months time frame (Q3 2011).

Source: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/May-16.html

**UPDATE 2011-07-18:**
Xamarin obtained a perpetual license to all the intellectual property of Mono, MonoTouch, Mono for Android, Mono for Visual Studio and will continue updating and selling those products.

Source: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Jul-18.html

Comment: Thank you for that info :: I will sit tight until next week.

Comment: So, it seems like it's going to be around for awhile more; that's excellent news.

Comment: In fact it even could be better for mono/mobile this way. Having been harbored in a company focused solely on this task vs being a part of big company with many different responsibilities. Can't wait for the first public release.